# Poincaré Sections with periodicity for non linear system

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to calculate the Poincare section for this system of equation at different on Mathematica initial conditions
\begin{align}
x'(t)&=-0.1 x(t) y(t)^2-0.02 x(t) z(t) \sin ( \omega t )-y(t) (0.2 (\sin ( \omega t )+1)-z(t)),\\
y'(t)&=0.1 x(t)^2 y(t)+0.5 x(t) \sin ( \omega t )+0.05 y(t) z(t) (z(t)-0.2 (\sin ( \omega t )+1)),\\
z'(t)&=-x(t) y(t)-0.02 x(t)^2 \sin ( \omega t )+0.05 y(t)^2 (z(t)-0.2\sin (\omega t  ))
\end{align}

(based on https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-9/advanced-hybrid-and-differential-algebraic-equations/poincare-sections.html) I did the following:

```
data = Block[{W = 1},
         Reap[
           NDSolve[
             {x'[t] == -(0.1*x[t]*y[t]^2 + 0.02*x[t]*z[t]*Sin[W t] + y[t]*(-z[t] + 0.2*(1 + Sin[W t]))),
              y'[t] == 0.1*x[t]^2*y[t] + 0.5*x[t]*Sin[W t] + 0.05*y[t]*z[t]*(z[t] - 0.2*(1 + Sin[W t])),
              z'[t] == -(x[t]*y[t] - 0.02*x[t]^2*Sin[W t] + 0.05*y[t]^2*(z[t] - 0.2*(Plus[Sin[t W]]))),
              x[0] == 0, y[0] == 0.1, z[0] == Sqrt[1 - x[0]*x[0] - y[0]*y[0]], 
              WhenEvent[Mod[W t, 2*Pi] == 1, Sow[{x[t], y[t]}]]},
             {}, {t, 100, 10000}, MaxSteps -> Infinity]
            ]
          ][[-1,1]]; 
ListPlot[data, ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.01]]
```

How to calculate the periodicity for the given values at different initial conditions. i.e. I need to make loop for different initial values and if we have one point in the Poincare section for the given initial condition we have P1 motion, two point we have P2 motion, etc.

Any suggestions?

The result for one initial condition look like
[image]

Comment: You need to put mathematica code instead of latex. People here can be very lazy and often skip questions if they can't copy paste from it ;)

Comment: Why not put the Mathematica code directly.

Comment: I added the code Just if you copy it should work.

Comment: The built-in function [PoincareSection](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/EquationTrekker/ref/PoincareSection.html) might be what you want.